# Angular SwPush only default action works

Tags: angular, web-push

I'm trying to figure out why my push notifications won't work.
I'm sending the following payload:

```js
{
  title: 'Some title',
  body: `Some body`,
  actions: [{ action: 'foo', title: 'some action' }],
  data: {
    onActionClick: {
      default: { operation: 'openWindow', url: url },
      foo: { operation: 'openWindow', url: url },
    },
  },
}
```

When I receive this notification I see a button with `some action` as text. But when I click on it nothing happens.

If I just click on the notification it opens the url (also if I don't define any actions it also works)

What am I doing wrong?